# Unterschied Mietvertrag - Anmietvertrag

Tags: meaning, difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen einem Mietvertrag und einem Anmietvertrag?

Comment: Ohne es zu wissen, aber ich glaube, da gibt es keinen Unterschied.

Comment: @Em1: Wissend, dass es sich um 2 verschiedene Datenbank-Tabellen handelt, macht es einen Unterschied.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ich selbst habe das Wort *Anmietvertrag* vorher noch nie bewusst gelesen oder gehört. Eine Google-Suche nach ["Anmietvertrag"](http://www.google.de/#q="anmietvertrag") liefert im Moment nur 508 Ergebnisse, während es bei ["Mietvertrag"](http://www.google.de/#q="mietvertrag") fast 4 Millionen Ergebnisse sind. Interessanterweise sind anscheinendend [274 der 508 Ergebnisse](http://www.google.de/#q="anmietvertrag"+"sap") (also mehr als die Hälfte) aus dem [SAP](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAP)-Umfeld. Von dem restlichen haben [immerhin 99](http://www.google.de/#q="anmietvertrag"+"auto"+-sap) mit Autos zu tun.

Bei der Verwendung außerhalb des SAP-Umfeldes spekuliere ich, dass es keinen Unterschied zwischen den beiden Wörtern gibt, und dass *Anmietvertrag* eine leicht aufgeblähte Variante ist, die etwas wichtiger klingt `:-)`

Angeregt durch John Smithers spekuliere ich weiter, dass der Begriff *Anmietvertrag* von SAP eingeführt wurde, um in Datenbankeinträgen zu differenzieren, ob ein Objekt *angemietet* oder *vermietet* wird (ob also Geld ausgegeben oder eingenommen wird). Trotz dieser Herleitung *anmieten → Anmietvertrag* finde ich den Begriff recht unglücklich: Ein Mietvertrag wird immer von zwei Parteien unterzeichnet, einer *vermietenden* und einer *anmietenden* – der Vertrag ist für beide derselbe.

Comment: Ich glaube eher, der Begriff wurde eingeführt, um Mietverträge zu unterscheiden, bei denen man Vermieter ist von denen wo man (An-)mieter ist: http://help.sap.com/saphelp_wp/helpdata/de/36/1875ce6e213b7ce10000009b38f9b7/content.htm

Comment: @John: Das habe ich auch erst gedacht. Aber so ein Vertrag wird von beiden Seiten unterzeichnet, und eine Seite ist doch immer der Vermieter - oder mache ich hier einen Fehler?

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Ich kam zum gleichen Schluss via google. Nur muss es einen unterschied geben, denn es sind zwei verschiedene Datenbanktabellen :)) Möglicherweise enden Anmietverträge automatisch, während Mietverträge möglicherweise rollover sind.

Comment: @John: Spekulierst Du auch oder weißt Du Genaueres? `:-)` Mich wundert, dass Google nur 508 Ergebnisse bringt, wenn es sich um einen wohletablierten Begriff im Vertragsrecht handelt!

Comment: @John: Nein, hast Du nicht. Ich bin nur drauf gekommen, weil's ja um Verträge geht. Ich denke, dass Du bezüglich SAP recht hast mit Deiner Unterscheidung - vielleicht ist das schon eine Antwort wert? (Ich habe meine Spekulation entsprechend abgeschwächt.)

Comment: @Quandary: Ah - es wäre nett, wenn Du dies mit ein paar Details noch in Deine Frage einbaust. Interessant wäre z.B., um was für eine Datenbank es geht. (Ich habe meine Antwort entsprechend angepasst.)

Comment: @John: Erledigt `:-)`

Comment: Nach eingehender Recherche bin ich auf dasselbe Ergebnis bzw. dieselbe Schlussfolgerung gekommen. Es geht um [CAFM-Systeme](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_facility_management), wo [SAP anscheinend Softwarelösungen anbietet](http://www.emphetaion.com/de/cafm). Ich vermute, dass sich irgendwo in dieser Software die Begriffe *Anmietvertrag* und *Vermietvertrag* finden werden.

Comment: Danke, ist korrigiert. Aufgrund Deines CAFM-Fundes habe ich übrigens noch [eine CAFM-Richtlinie der Stadt Zürich](http://www.stadt-zuerich.ch/content/dam/stzh/hbd/Deutsch/Immobilienbewirtschaftung/Formulare%20und%20Merkblaetter/Zbgg/cafm_richtlinie_v16_18012010.pdf) gefunden.

Comment: @John: Sollen wir ein paar von unseren Kommentaren entfernen? Fang Du bitte an, ich folge dann.